# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION - bad class file magic - Netbean and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, netbeans, gradle, java-8

I spent a lot of time trying to fix this issue, but without success.
I read here several similar issues, but the solutions weren't OK for me.

I have some different projects (app for PC) realised using Netbeans; I share some java classes between those projects without any problem. Those shared classes are inside a my "Fausto_Library" project and the other netbeans projects see the shared classes. When I build "Fausto_Library" project a Fausto_Library.jar file is created.

Now I want to use "Fausto_Library" in Android Studio for an Android project.
Inside my Android Studio project, I edited the "buil.gradle" adding the line:

```
compile files('..../NetBeanProjects/Fausto_Library/dist/Fausto_Library.jar')
```

The Fausto_Library classes are correctly inserted and visible inside the Android Studio project in "External Libraries".

When I try to build the Android Studio project I got the following error:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing Cache/BounceServerData.class
>   1 error; aborting
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Fausto\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:_F\PoIP\AndroidStudioProjects\Iptetraclient\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\Fausto_Library-08b2fbc417f5770af9a3e586a402b42c73787b91.jar C:_F\PoIP\NetBeanProjects\Fausto_Library\dist\Fausto_Library.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       ...while parsing Cache/BounceServerData.class
>       1 error; aborting

I read some posts in SO saying that:

- could be different java versions used in Netbean and Android Studio,     but I checked and in both cases it'used SDK 1.8.0_31. I tried also to    use in both Android and Netbean SDK 1.7 but nothing changed
- could be some duplicated libraries, but I don't see them, and when I tried to adopt some suggested solutions it didn't work;  for example I tried      to remove the line "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'" but I got then a lot of different errors because some codes need that library.

I'm really disappointed for this issue, can anybody help me??
Thank you in advance,
Fausto

Comment: The problem should be with the jdk version used. Are you sure to use the 1.7 in Android Studio and Netbean?

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the version in both Netbean and Android must be the same, or do you mean that in addition to be the same it's better to use 1,7 instead of 1.8? In any case, I already tried to set, in both Android and Netbean, the SDK 1.7.0_71, but it din't work, I got the same error. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Hi again, at the end of the story I wasn't able to find the solution; I changed strategy: instead of to import a .jar (then a compiled library) I simply imported the .java files. It is possible using inside build.gradle:  sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += '......./NetBeanProjects/Fausto_Library/src'
    }. now it works!!! If you found my solution usefull please increase my reputation  :-)   Thank you